# I have setup the ElasticSearch on my ubuntu but when i try to run sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service i got an error

Tags: elasticsearch

I have install ES using the [Install ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html)
Error:

```
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service:

elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-10-14 02:30:18 PKT; 4min 51s ago
       


/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log:


org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: invalid configuration for xpack.security.transport.ssl - [xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled] is >
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:67) ~[elasticsearch-8.4.3.jar:?]
```

Here is my **elasticsearch.yml** file
etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:

```
======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
 NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.

 The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
 the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.

 Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html

 ---------------------------------- Cluster ----------------------------------

 Use a descriptive name for your cluster:

cluster.name: my-application

 ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------

 Use a descriptive name for the node:

node.name: node-1

 Add custom attributes to the node:

node.attr.rack: r1


 ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------

 Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch

 Path to log files:

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch

 ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------

 Lock the memory on startup:

bootstrap.memory_lock: true

 Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
 on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
 limit.

 Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.

 ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------

 By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
 address here to expose this node on the network:

network.host: localhost

 By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
 finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:

http.port: 9200

 For more information, consult the network module documentation.

 --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------

 Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
 The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]

discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]

 Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]

 For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.

 --------------------------------- Readiness ----------------------------------

 Enable an unauthenticated TCP readiness endpoint on localhost

readiness.port: 9399

 ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------

 Allow wildcard deletion of indices:

action.destructive_requires_name: false
```

I'm using OS **Ubuntu 22.04** and install ES on this OS.

Is there any issue in my **elasticsearch.yml** file?
If Yes then what changes should I make to cope with this error , any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you "check the logs at /var/log/elasticsearch"?

Comment: yes i have update the question, kindly revisit it.

Comment: can you please use code formatting to clean things up, it's very hard to read as is